# Crystal report split whole group into multiple columns cross and down

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a report and need group data to split into multiple columns horizontally like this:

Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3

Details 1 | Details 2 | Details 3

Header 4 | Header 5 | Header 6

Details 4 | Details 5 | Details 6

Header 7 | Header 8 | Header 9

Details 7 | Details 8 | Details 9

......

"Format With Multiple Columns" is only available for the Detail section, and I selected "Across and Down" int the Printing Direction option, now I'm getting this:

Header 1 | Details 1 |Header 2

Details 2 | Header 3 | Details 3

Header 4 | Details 4 | Header 5

Details 5 | Header 6 | Details 6

Header 7 | Details 7 | Header 8

Details 8 | Header 9 | Details 9

....

Is there any way to get the desired result?

Thank you.​

Answer (score 0):

According to your second example I assume your dataset includes what you named "Header x" as data (not column name) as well as "Details x".

If you're able to clearly identify rows that contain "Details", you could achieve the desired result by

- creating a new formula field that shows the content of the "next" data row: `Next({your column name here})`
- and suppress detail section conditionally if row contains "Details" data.